# Relationship between t and F values in multiple regression

Tags: regression, t-test, f-test

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, but I checked all recommended threads and haven't found a clear answer to this particular question.

I understand that in a simple linear regression with a single IV, the t-statistic for the coeffcient is equal to the square root of the overall F-statistic that tests whether all coefficients are jointly zero. This makes perfect sense. However, I can't find anything on whether there is a similar mathematical relationship between the overall F-value and t-values for individual IVs in multiple regression. No individual t-value seems to be the square root of F, and the squared t-values don't add up to F either. I'd be grateful if someone could illuminate the mathematical relationship between them, if one exists.

Comment: You can have extremely insignificant t-stats and an extremely significant F-stat if the predictors have strong correlation.

Comment: That much is clear, but I'm asking about the mathematical relationship. With a single predictor, F = t^2. Is there a similar relationship between multiple t values and the overall F-value?

Comment: Short answer: no, unless the explanatory variables are orthogonal.

Comment: Thanks! If they were orthogonal, would there be a known relationship?